# Apache Server configuration Virtual Hosts

Tags: virtualhost, apache

There is simple question, but i can't understand why it's not working.

I have apache 2.2 and I want to work with 2 ports. For example

http://site.com:8888

and

http://site.com:7777

there is httpd.conf configuration

```
Listen 8888
Listen 7777

<VirtualHost *:8888>   
     DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:7777>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/doc"
</VirtualHost>
```

8888 works, but 7777 not. Why?

Comment: Page loading, then no response.

Comment: Is `site.com:7777` reachable? Tried to `netcat` or `telnet` to it? What do the server's log files state?

Answer (score 0):

Why the 'VirtualHost *:7777' string end with '/doc' ?
have you try without it?

Comment: because site.com:7777 with this port should show something different instead 8888. it's only for example